# Basic decryption for simple encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I have the following  encryption algorithm, to encode an alphabetic message.

In order to decipher it, how do I reverse the equation. Can someone enlighten me please?

```
if (OriginalChar + Key > 126)
     EncryptedChar = 32 + ((OriginalChar + Key) - 127);
else
     EncryptedChar = OriginalChar + Key;
```

Where:

1) *OriginalChar* can be ANY character from the ASCII character table,

2) *key* , can be any value between 1 - 100

How do I reverse this algorithm to decrypt a message please- anyone?

Comment: Actually, I've figured it out. thanks everyone.

Comment: I doubt that a key of 100 can be used. You probably mean 0 - 95.

Comment: This is for a college assignment for a friend of mine. The assignment states keys possible to range from 1 - 100. and that the C++ program should check for all permutations. So,it's just  simple school level stuff, not for real-world  cryptography. Thanks for  Pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0):

We iterate through each character(*CharInEncryptedString*) in the encrypted msg/string:

```
if (CharInEncryptedString  - Key <= 126)
    DecryptedChar  = CharInEncryptedString - Key;
else
    DecryptedChar = ((CharInEncryptedString - Key) + 127) -32;
```

Comment: That's not going to work. Your condition needs to be `CharInEncryptedString - Key >= 32`.

Comment: So, to summarize, you literally have the inverse of the function. What was the original question for? This seems like a really obvious solution to me, and I have to believe you tried something similar prior to posting?

Comment: @Artjom - thank you. The encrypted message is :  :mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy and when decrypting, I'm getting :  !TTACK_AT_DAWN`    Is this correct?